# why $\alpha_i \mu(A_i\cap E)$ is come in $\int_{E} s d\mu$?

Tags: measure-theory

I have some confusion in Rudin RCA book statement , my doubt is  given below marked in red circle [image]

If  $E \in \mathcal{M}$, we define $$ \int_{E} s d\mu = \sum_{i}^{n} \alpha_i \mu(A_i\cap E)$$

**My doubt** why  $\alpha_i \mu(A_i\cap E)$ is come in  $\int_{E} s d\mu$ ?

Note : Im focusing on $(A_i\cap E)$

Comment: Just see what happens when you take $s=\chi_A$ and$A,E$ are intervals in the real line.

Comment: oks @Kavi sir u mean that  suppose  $A=[a, b]$ and $E=[c,d]$ 
$$s=
\chi_{[a, b]}(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{c@{,\quad}l} 1 & x \in [a, b] \\ 0 & x \notin [a,b]. \end{array}\right.
$$

and then  $$ \int_{E} s d\mu=  \int_E\chi_A d\mu=\int_{[c,d]}d\mu   =  \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i \mu([c,d]\cap [a,b])$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $s$ is a measurable simple function, it returns a finite amount of values $\alpha_i$, each of them in a measurable set $A_i$, so it would make sense to define its integral over a set $E$ as some kind of "how much of each $\alpha_i$ is in $E$", which can be taken as "how much $A_i$ intersects with $E$, so we can take $\alpha_i$ for our integral all over that region". Now, the definition $\int_{E} s d\mu=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i \mu(A_i\cap E)$ does exactly that: it measures "how much each $\alpha_i$ is intersecting $E$" by taking the measure of the intersection, and then it multiplies that measure by $\alpha_i$, so we kind of have "the amount of each $\alpha_i$ that is in $E$". Summing together these amounts we get the "total contribution of every $\alpha_i$ in $E$".